# mixture of 2 Gaussians and using a priori information about one of the Gaussians

Tags: distributions, bayesian, clustering, estimation, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I am working on a large dataset of 2 populations, 
one is healthy controls and other is considered to be dysfunctional
My variables interests suggest a good fit for a unitary Gaussian distribution for controls but bimodal distribution for pathological group

Our hypothesis is pathological group is a mixture of 2 subgroups: one which has identical Gaussian distribution with controls and other is a different Gaussian that significantly deviates from controls (difference is likely around 1.5 SD)

What is your suggestion (software and approach, Bayesian or non-Bayesian) to fit 2 Gaussian model and characterize curves, distributions and other characteristics of each of them (percentage of individuals in each subtype etc..) and using information from controls to estimation of the theoretically identical Gaussian?

Comment: EM is a flexible framework. You can use constrained distributions, where e.g. mean or standard deviation are fixed, or even everything.